# Python, linux: Using wifi Cell and Scheme, how do I connect to a network?

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, subprocess, wifi

For reference: https://wifi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scanning.html#connecting-to-a-network

I have been successful in getting a list of wireless networks, by executing the following commands:

```
from wifi import Cell, Scheme
cells = list(Cell.all('wlan0'))
my_wifi_cell = cells[some_index]
```

But when I try to use it (as in the example above):

```
scheme = Scheme.for_cell('wlan0', 'home', my_wifi_cell, 'my password')
scheme.save()
scheme.activate()
```

While running python elevated, scheme.activate() fails with the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/wifi/scheme.py", line 172, in activate
   subprocess.check_output(['sbin/ifdown', self.interface], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
 File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 395, in check_output
   **kwargs).stdout
 File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 487, in run
   output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: command '['/sbin/ifdown', 'wlan0']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Sorry if there are any mistakes, I had to manually type that over. Anyway, I verified that the ssid and passkey were correct, I'm just not sure how to resolve this error. Any thoughts?

Update:
According to https://github.com/rockymeza/wifi/issues it looks like this just doesn't work anymore(?) Is there a fix for this, or should I just start looking somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are missing is root privilege. Let try to run it with root

Comment: Good theory, but I forgot to mention I did try this with root already.
When run without root, it simply tells me that access is denied when trying to save the scheme.

Comment: Can you manually run "/sbin/ifdown wlan0" to see if you encounter any error?

Comment: Running "sudo /sbin/ifdown wlan0" results in -- ifdown: interface wlan0 not configured

Comment: I think you first need to resolve mentioned issue "not configured". Try to config that interface with below config:
"vi    /etc/network/interfaces"
-- Add the following
"auto wlan0 
iface wlan0 inet loopback"

Similar question can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44154053/python-wifi-subprocess-calledprocesserror-command-sbin-ifdown-wlp4s0/44934382